# PHP agi Goto Queue

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I have a problem with my Asterisk Agi.

My script checks if the customer id is correct and then it has to transfer the call into a queue.

I use:

```
$agi->exec('Goto',"ext-queues,100,0");
```

But when I call the number, give an existing customer number it terminate the call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have exit AGI script after goto.

Better not use that, it can work unpredictable.

For more info see

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 3
agi set debug on
```